How do I defer loading of an external CSS file in Next.js 14
I need to load Katex CSS to style math equations. I don't know ahead of time exactly which pages need it (it depends on which users include math in their posts), but I do know which routes might need it.
For more context, here's a page with math and here's one without math.

Currently, I'm loading the CSS using a <link> tag in the header of my root layout, like this.
// src/app/layout.jsx

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.8/dist/katex.min.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <main>
         { children }
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

This strategy makes it a "render blocking resource" as you can see from my lighthouse report.

If it's possible, I would prefer to load the CSS lazily AND dynamically, depending on if the current page has math that needs styling.
I've read the docs on CSS and lazy loading, but I'm still scratching my head on how to accomplish this.

You can use the import function.
So first you can check whether the content has ant math equation or not and if it has, you'll import your library dynamically.


if(/* content has math equation */) {
  conte Katex = (await import(/* path to the library */)).default;
}



You can read more here.
And also you can use the Head component which lets you to add your desired meta tags in the html.


import Head from 'next/head'
 
function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
      </Head>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}
 
export default IndexPage



You can read more here.

Can you elaborate, perhaps providing more code? If I add const Katex = (await import("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.8/dist/katex.min.css")).default to my page.jsx, I get the error "UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.8/dist/katex.min.css" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme)."

Actually in your case the second method (Using Head component) is more suitable. You can render the Head component conditionally based on your condition.

<Head> is for Next.js pages. I'm using the app router.

Technically all stylesheets without disabled or media attributes are render-blocking resources. To get rid of them, there is no perfect answer. There is only best-fit answer. I would like to provide an answer for all the What, Why, and How questions so that you can easily deal with other similar situations.
What is render-blocking resources
Google documented it very clearly:

Lighthouse flags two types of render-blocking URLs: scripts and stylesheets.
A <script> tag that:

Is in the <head> of the document.
Does not have a defer attribute.
Does not have an async attribute.

A <link rel="stylesheet"> tag that:

Does not have a disabled attribute. When this attribute is present,the browser does not download the stylesheet.
Does not have a media attribute that matches the user's device specifically. media="all" is considered render-blocking.


Why are they render-blocking resources?
In short, this is how the browser renders your website.

This image is taken from this awesome article How to Eliminate Render-Blocking Resources: a Deep Dive. Strongly recommend you to read the whole article to get the full picture.
To start rendering a web page, the browser needs to construct both DOM and CSSOM.
To build DOM, the browser needs to download the HTML. But Synchronous JS in the head can modify the DOM so the browser will wait to download and execute all these scripts before continuing to build the DOM. Remember the keyword here is Synchronous JS. async, defer, and module scrips will not block rendering.
To build the CSSOM, the browser obviously needs to download all CSS. So CSS is render-blocking resources
How to rid of render-blocking CSS
The strategy is: only load critical CSS and defer everything else.
What is critical CSS?
Critical CSS is the essential CSS required to render the above-the-fold content of a webpage.
What is the above-the-fold content?
Above-the-fold content refers to the portion of a webpage that is visible without scrolling. It is the content the user sees first when a page loads.
Keep in mind that, the above-the-fold content varies by the screen size. So you need to define what is your above-the-fold content based on the device. At least you need one version for mobile and the other one for desktop.
How to load critical CSS and lazy-load others?
<!-- load critical CSS as usual -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="critical.css">

<!-- load non-critical CSS with a preload link and low fetchPriority -->
<link rel="preload" href="non-critical.css" as="style" fetchPriority="low" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="non-critical.css"></noscript>

A link preload will fetch your CSS without blocking the renderer. When it finishes downloading, the onload handler will kick in and change the rel to stylesheet. Now your CSS will be applied.
fetchPriority="low" mark your non-critical CSS as low priority. Browser will give bigger bandwidth for higher priority resources.
Why not lazy-load all CSS?
If you lazy load critical CSS, your webpage will suffer from Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC). It gives the worst user experience.
Apply to your website
Based on the links that you provided, I can assume that the math block might be above the fold only on the desktop. So the katex CSS is critical CSS on desktop and non-critical CSS on mobile. So we can load it like that:
<!-- Need a little bit tricky here to inject raw HTML to the head tag. I hate Nextjs in this part :-) -->
const RawHtml = ({ html = "" }) => (
  <noscript
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `</noscript>${html}<noscript>` }}
  />
);

<head>
  {isUseMath() && isDeskTop() && (<RawHtml html={`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.8/dist/katex.min.css">`}/>)}
  {isUseMath() && !isDeskTop() && (<RawHtml html={`<link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.8/dist/katex.min.css" as="style" fetchPriority="low" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">`}/>)}
</head>

Update: Another way to insert style from page.tsx

For critical CSS use react-dom preinit API to add the link from SSR:

// page.tsx
if (isUseMath() && isDesktop()) {
  preinit("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.8/dist/katex.min.css", {
    as: "style",
  });
}


For non-critical CSS, use a client component to add the style on the client via useInsertionEffect hook

// page.tsx
{isUseMath() && !isDesktop() && <ClientComponent />}

"use client";

// ClientComponent.tsx

import { useInsertionEffect } from "react";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  // add style on the client side
  useInsertionEffect(() => {
    const link: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.8/dist/katex.min.css";
    link.id = "katex-css";
    document.head.appendChild(link);
    // cleanup function
    return () => {
      const linkElm = document.getElementById("katex-css");
      if (linkElm) {
        linkElm.remove();
      }
    };
  });
  return null
}



Thanks this is very informative, but 1) it produces the error "app-index.js:33 Warning: Prop dangerouslySetInnerHTML did not match. Server: "" Client: "</noscript>..." and 2) I feel like it makes more sense to load the CSS from my page.jsx file since that's where I fetch the requested post and thus can check if it contains math. AFAIK, I can't use <head> tags in page.jsx


I think we can ignore it. I've not seen any problem so far. 2. How about fetching data inside your layout? @Ben


fetching data in layout.jsx won't work. It defeats the purpose of layout which is to preserve state and not re-render between page navigations. Fetching the data for a post should be done in the relevant post.jsx file.

@Ben Okay. So we have another way to add CSS from page.tsx. Please see my updated answer. Btw, I still hate Nextjs :)

Have you checked this doc https://katex.org/docs/node?
yarn add katex
yarn build

On your component import katex from 'katex';
Then check https://katex.org/docs/api

Theres a quick and easy way to do this.
create a local css file
import the external css file into the local css file
// externalstyles.css
@import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.8/dist/katex.min.css'

import/require the local css file into your JSX file
// src/app/layout.jsx
// option 1: static import
import './externalstyles'
import { default as externalstyles} './externalstyles.css'

// with the named import option you can try injecting the css directly in the JSX (untested)

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {

  if(someCondition)
  {
     // option 2: dynamic lazy loaded import with Ract lazy loader
     const styles = React.lazy(() => import("./externalstyles.css"));

     // option: 3 OR dynamic loader with good old require
     const styles = require('./externalstyles.css')
  }


  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning lang="en">
      <head>
        <link type="text/css">
          // for the nembed import option
          {externalstyles}
        </link>
      </head>
      <body>
        <main>
         { children }
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

;)

Mind posting some code?

updated hope it helps

Thanks. I think your imports are messed up. Did you mean to name that CSS file externalstyles.css?

ah yeh typo, renamed it to make the context clearer but missed the first comment
